# How to Get Current Address accurately using Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, laravel-5.1

Im trying to get my current location but the problem is the address which the marker points is only the nearest street where I am now. How can I get my place accurately?

Heres the screen shot. Thanks in advance :) 
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVQrd.jpg)

```
<input type="button" value="Show Location" onclick="showlocation()"/> 

<br/>
    Latitude: <span id="latitude">..</span> <br>
    Longitude: <span id="longitude">..</span><br>
    Address: <span id="add">..</span><br>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script>

    function showlocation(){

        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(callback);

    }
    function callback(position){
        document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML=position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML=position.coords.longitude;
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        geocoder.geocode({       
            latLng: latLng     
            }, 
            function(responses) 
            {     
               if (responses && responses.length > 0) 
               {        
                   address(responses[0].formatted_address);     
               } 
               else 
               {       
                 alert('Not getting Any address for given latitude and longitude.');     
               }   
            }
    );
    } 
        function address(str) 
        {
          document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = str;
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: Have you tried geolocation and how far off is it? Where is the example point?

Comment: I tried geolocation sir @adin but the requirement is it should be accurate.

Comment: I already inserted my code sir @duncan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Geolocation API. To obtain your current location, you can call the `getCurrentPosition()` method. This initiates an asynchronous request to detect the user's position, and queries the positioning hardware to get up-to-date information.

> When the position is determined, the defined callback function is executed. You can optionally provide a second callback function to be executed if an error occurs. A third, optional, parameter is an options object where you can set the maximum age of the position returned, the time to wait for a request, and if you want high accuracy for the position.

This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation) and [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) might help you.